# Angular file upload unit test with ( event: HttpEvent<any> ) parameter couldn't cover full code

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm using angular version 9. In my application I'm having file upload method with functionality to show file upload progress.

Code is got cover up to first switch case ( case HttpEventType.Sent ), couldn't cover the remaining code.

ts:

```
uploadFile() {
    
    this.up.uploadFileModel(this.file, this.selectedModel)
      .subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        switch (event.type) {
          case HttpEventType.Sent:
            console.log('Request has been made!');
            break;
          case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader:
            console.log('Response header has been received!');
            break; 
          case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
            this.progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
            console.log(`Uploaded! ${this.progress}%`);
            break;
          case HttpEventType.Response:
            console.log('File successfully uploaded !', event.body, event);
            if (event.status == 200) {
              this.uploadMsg = event.body;
              this.uploadStatus = true;
            } else {
              this.uploadMsg = 'File upload failed! some thing went wrong'
              this.uploadStatus = false;
            }
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.uploadStatus = true;
            console.log("testing correction", "uploadMsg:",  this.uploadMsg, "uploadStatus: ", this.uploadStatus);
            this.router.navigate(['/home'], {state: {data: {uploadMsg: this.uploadMsg, uploadStatus: this.uploadStatus} }});
          }, 1000); 
        }
      }, err => {
        this.uploadMsg = err;
        this.progress = 0;
        this.uploadStatus = false;
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

spec file
```

```
it('should create upload template', () => {
    //component.selectedModel = { id: 2, name: 'NER', code: 'NER' };
    const mockFile = [ { 0: { name: 'foo', size: 500001 }, 1: { name: 'foo', size: 500001 } }];

    spyOn(component, 'uploadFile').and.callThrough();
    
    component.uploadFile();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    spyOn(service, 'uploadFileModel').and.returnValue(of(
      {
        result : {
           httpStatus : 200
        }
      }
    ));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.uploadFile).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(service.uploadFileModel).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Comment: How to travel through switch case to cover 100% code, how to check for http event type!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your order does not seem correct, you have to `spyOn` the service `uploadFileModel` before calling `component.uploadFile`.

```
it('should create upload template', () => {
    //component.selectedModel = { id: 2, name: 'NER', code: 'NER' };
    const mockFile = [ { 0: { name: 'foo', size: 500001 }, 1: { name: 'foo', size: 500001 } }];

    // spyOn(component, 'uploadFile').and.callThrough(); // get rid of this line
    spyOn(service, 'uploadFileModel').and.returnValue(of( // move this here
      {
        // mock the return here
        type: HttpEventType.Sent, // This time Sent will be traversed.
        body: {}
        status: 200,
        loaded: 0,
      }
    ));
    component.uploadFile();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // expect(component.uploadFile).toHaveBeenCalled(); // get rid of this line, we explicitly called it so obviously it was called.
    expect(service.uploadFileModel).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

To traverse the other cases write another unit test (it block) and change the type of the mock return.